# How can you assign a custom shortcut to stop a QuickTime screen recording?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, screen-capture, quicktime

I am looking to record my screen using QuickTime on my Mac, but stopping a screen recording requires you to press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>. I would like to know if it is possible to create a custom keyboard shortcut, such as <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, to stop the QuickTime recording.

I prefer not clicking the Stop button in the menu bar because the recording captures the mouse trailing up to click that button.

If it is possible, how can one create a custom shortcut to stop a QuickTime screen recording?

Comment: The easiest thing I have found for this is to wait for about 5 seconds when you are finished *before* you end the video so you have a buffer of video.  Then click the stop.  Trim out the extra frames so you don't see the mouse moving.

Comment: I do leave room at the end and trim it but I would love have a short-cut I can remember. Plus, the 'Command+Control+Esc' function is awkward. During a recording, my brain is slow to signal my index finger (COMMAND), thumb (CONTROL) and pinky finger (ESC) to get into position to execute the stop function.

Comment: (IMO) That default key combo is designed that you have to use 2 hands to prevent inadvertent invocation.  `Ctrl-Cmd-S` is *much* easier to do with one hand than `Ctrl-Cmd-Esc`.

Answer (score 16):

You may use the default stop recording shortcut: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> to stop recording when you finished.

Answer (score 7):

This can be accomplished using an Automator Service bound to a custom keyboard shortcut, as follows:

- Open Automator (`/Applications/Utilities/Automator.app`) and create a new `Service`.
- At the top, set this service to receive `no input` in `any application`.
- Use the search bar on the left side to find the `Run AppleScript` action and drag it into the main workflow pane on the right side.
- Set the contents of the `Run AppleScript` to the following:

  ```
  on run
      tell first document of application "QuickTime Player" to stop
  end run
  ```
- Save the Service under a name you'll remember (perhaps "Stop QuickTime Recording").
- Open System Preferences, go to Keyboard preferences, go to the `Shortcuts` tab, select `Services` from the menu on the left, and find the Service you just created (it's probably located under `Text`). Click on it to select it, then click the `Add Shortcut` button.
- Press the keyboard shortcut you want to assign to this action (<kbd>⌃</kbd>-<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>).

You can then close System Preferences and Automator. From now on, any time you press that key combination, it will attempt to stop the first active recording in QuickTime Player, including screen recordings.

Comment: Thx for this detailed and accurate walk through. I had not made an `Automator` service before. it is called `Quick Action` in `mojave`

Answer (score 1):

To end the recording you can press: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, or press the ⏺ (stop recording) button on your Macbook's touchbar. (see [Apple Support > QuickTime Player](https://support.apple.com/en-sa/guide/quicktime-player/qtp97b08e666/10.5/mac/11.0))

---

To alter the shortcut, you would need to know what the name of the command is and rebind it in:

**System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts**

You could also consider using software that intercepts keys and runs arbitrary actions, e.g.: [Alfred (workflows)](https://www.alfredapp.com/), [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/), [Hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/).