# Applescript - create a shortcut to control several applications simultaneously?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, quicktime

I have two instances of the Quicktime application running.  I use two different video sources (Facetime camera and iPhone camera via USB), and I use "Movie recording" to record them. I also have Spotify running.

I want to initiate "Record" in both Quicktime apps as well as initiate the "Play" command on the Spotify app at the same time via one key press.

I have read this solution using Automator to create a Service with a shortcut here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/334857/439929.

```
on run
    tell first document of application "QuickTime Player" to start
end run
```

I created a service for both QT apps and assigned the same keyboard shortcut to start both.  I also assigned a shortcut to stop recording.  When I  tested, two problems occurred:

1. Only the second instance of QT player will record, irrespective of which is in the foreground.
2. When I stopped recording, a dialogue with “Finishing Recording” came up and would not disappear, even though the recording was finished.  This doesn’t happen when stopping the recording by clicking the on screen stop button.

I then added Spotify using the same process, with the same keyboard combination.  Spotify will only play when the QT apps are disabled in System Preferences.

I realise my approach is flawed, but I’m not sure if there is a way to achieve this.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, while the synopsis of what you are doing is relevant, nonetheless there is too much missing information in your question! 1. What version of **macOS** are you running and on what _model_ of **Mac**? 2. What type of **Automator** _workflow_ and what are the settings and layout of it? 3. How are you instigating the two instances of **QuickTime Player**? 4. What is the rest of the **AppleScript** _code_ you are using?

Comment: Thanks for responding to my post, I appreciate it.  Sorry for the lack of detail.
1. OS Mojave 10.14.6, MacBook Pro 2015 2.2Gz Core i7
2. I followed the instructions referenced above to create a Service (Quick Action).
The Workflow receives “no input” in Any application.  
3. I’m not sure what you mean by this - I made a copy of QT player.  They can run simultaneously recording input from different devices.
4. This is the entire script (above) - also copied from the reference above.
I hope this helps to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be in one workflow, so there is no conflict.  This is the script I used:

```
on run
    tell first document of application "Spotify" to play
    tell first document of application "QuickTime Player" to start
    tell first document of application "QuickTime Player 2" to start
end run
```

It appears that Spotify needs to be first, otherwise there is an error.